# WordPress loop: exclude if it is the latest post

Tags: loop

I do not want to show the latest post on a particular page. I am using a loop per category as I require these loops on various pages.

So the thing is, I am running 3 separate loops for each category, so I cannot use 'offset' => '1' on each loop as the latest post won't always be in all the categories.

I am using 'orderby' => 'menu_order', so I need a rule that says "show posts unless the post's menu order is 1"

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own queries for these loops, all you have to do is to use `post__not_in` param in these queries.

This way you will exclude given post from these loops.

And to get the ID of first post, just use [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) with `'fields' => 'ids'`